# What do the numbers and colours represent for -vismv and vis_mb_type in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

After the `-vismv` command I have seen a number of different values given. I can't find any explanation of what the number does and from changing it – can't see any difference!

Also, I am working with the `-debug vis_mb_type` command and can visualise the block types. Red being new, but what do the green and uncoloured represent? I also saw purple in some files when on an I-frame!

Example command on an MP4 file:

```
ffmpeg -debug vis_mb_type -vismv 1 -i inputfile.mp4 -vcodec mjpeg -q:v 0 output.avi
```

Edit:
Doing a bit more digging on this.... I believe that the Green blocks are predicted but not moved and then the monochrome uncoloured blocks are unchanged from the I frame. Still can't figure out the red/purple though!

Comment: See the update of my answer.

Comment: Nice one! That will help... I will do a bit more research now on the various conditions.

Answer (score 3):

#### `vismv` options

There are no numbers to be passed to `-vismv` as arguments. Only these are supported:

- `pf` – forward predicted MVs of P-frames
- `bf` – forward predicted MVs of B-frames
- `bb` – backward predicted MVs of B-frames

I assume that if you use integers these are mapped to 1, 2 and 3, respectively.

#### `vis_mb_type`

I looked through the code and found the matching part in `mpegvideo.c`, starting from line 2029. It converts `COLOR(theta, r)` values into *U* and *V* values from a YUV color space using the following function:

```
#define COLOR(theta, r) \
    u = (int)(128 + r * cos(theta * 3.141592 / 180)); \
    v = (int)(128 + r * sin(theta * 3.141592 / 180));
```

Here are the color values per macroblock type, including their UV values and the matching RGB color at *Y = 128*.

- [image]
  `COLOR(120, 48), UV(104, 169.57), RGB(184, 107, 86)`
  Condition: `IS_PCM (== MB_TYPE_INTRA_PCM)`
- [image]
  `COLOR(30, 48), UV(169.57, 152), RGB(160, 97, 200)`
  Condition: `IS_INTRA && IS_ACPRED) || IS_INTRA16x16`
- [image]
  `COLOR(90, 48), UV(128, 176), RGB(193, 94, 128)`
  Condition: `IS_INTRA4x4`
- [image]
  `COLOR(150, 48), UV(86.43, 152), RGB(160, 125, 55)`
  Condition: `IS_DIRECT`
- [image]
  `COLOR(170, 48), UV(80.73, 136.34), RGB(139, 138, 46)`
  Condition: `IS_GMC && IS_SKIP`
- [image]
  `COLOR(190, 48), UV(80.73, 119.66), RGB(116, 149, 46)`
  Condition: `IS_GMC`
- [image]
  `COLOR(240, 48), UV(104, 86.43), RGB(71, 165, 86)`
  Condition: `!USES_LIST(mb_type, 1))`
- [image]
  `COLOR(0, 48), UV(176, 128), RGB(128, 111, 211)`
  Condition: `!USES_LIST(mb_type, 0))`
- [image]
  `COLOR(300,48), UV(152, 86.43), RGB(71, 148, 169)`
  Condition: `USES_LIST(mb_type, 0) && USES_LIST(mb_type, 1))` – this is an `assert` so it may or may not abort program execution when the assertion fails.

I haven't tested this, but it seems about right to me. Information about the debugging switches and macroblock colors are also [explained on the FFmpeg wiki](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Debug/MacroblocksAndMotionVectors).