# In ffplay, the "-debug vis_mb_type" doesn't work

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to try options mentioned here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Debug/MacroblocksAndMotionVectors

I tried `ffplay -debug vis_mb_type my-file.mp4`, but it only showed a lot of console output. Here is the related part:

```
[NULL @ 01f55270] [Eval @ 05b5f12c] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'vis_mb_type'
[NULL @ 01f55270] Unable to parse option value "vis_mb_type"
[NULL @ 01f55270] Error setting option debug to value vis_mb_type.
```

What can be the cause? I use the self-compiled ffplay, maybe I did something wrong, but overwise it works fine.

The related code is in libavcodec/mpegvideo.c, according to [What do the numbers and colours represent for -vismv and vis_mb_type in ffmpeg?](https://superuser.com/questions/693429/what-do-the-numbers-and-colours-represent-for-vismv-and-vis-mb-type-in-ffmpeg/693654)

Comment: That option along with `vis_qp` was disabled in Mar 2017. Use the codecview filter.

Comment: `-vf codecview=qp` doesn't work either. Doesn't look like there is a replacement for `vis_mb_type`.

Comment: ok, downloaded the older version, it works.

Answer (score 0):

For me with ffmpeg 4.1 the way to do it (which I guessed by reading the output of `ffmpeg --help filter=codecview`) is to explicitly set the `qp` flag to `true`, i.e. `-vf codecview=qp=true`.

Comment: I did this using ffplay (`ffplay -debug -flags2 small.mp4 -vf codecview=qp=true`), but it doesn't play the video with colourized blocks for QP values, like I would expect. When I run it through ffmpeg, like so: `ffmpeg -i small.mp4 -vf codecview=qp=true small_qp.mp4` the resulting video doesn't have the display either.
What could be wrong?